# PHP : PHP auto load variable on each page

Tags: php

I have a constant

like `define('SITE_URL','http://somewebsite.com');`

I am using it on some pages

Some time also changing the value of that variable so that it is a pathetic task to go on each page and change the variable value .

Please suggest me some alternative  like some automatic class loader or any other method  .

Since it is my first PHP web so I am unable to decide what to do here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all a `define` is not a variable.

To use it in multiple pages, put all your defines in a separate PHP file, and include it in other php files when you want to use it.

**example:**

in *defines.php*:

```
define('SITE_URL','http://somewebsite.com');
```

in *page1.php*:

```
include 'defines.php';
// do stuff and use the define:
echo SITE_URL;  // <-- notice that there are no quotes
```

etc.

Comment: oh thanks for the suggestion and answer  this is the good way and fulfilling my requirement but i heard about automatic class loaders while the page gets called

Comment: Yes, but that deals with `classes` and not `defines` or `variables`

Comment: oh i have to follow the oops approach for that

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file with the variables, for example "variables.php", then on all the pages you want to use that variable you just do:

```
include("path_to_the_file/variable.php");
```

and you will have access to that variable, and you will able to change the value for that script.

---

If you want to change the value for all the scripts, use Session variables instead.
You will need to have

```
session_start();
```

on all the pages which uses that variable. For setting the variable:
$_SESSION['myVar'] = "value";

So anytime you need to access to that var you can"

```
echo $_SESSION['myVar'];
```

or you can change it's value:

```
$_SESSION['myVar'] = "new Value";
```

And it will be changed for the whole session.

remember to have `session_start()` so you can access it.